# Show/Hide Multiple Table Columns in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show/hide multiple related columns using either just CSS or javascript in an HTML table using checkboxes. For instance, if the "Beer" checkbox is checked I need to show all three columns related to Beer, if it is unchecked hide all three columns.

```
<html>
Show: <input type="checkbox">Beer</input>
<input type="checkbox">Wine</input>
<input type="checkbox">Vodka</input>
<input type="checkbox">Whiskey</input>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>BeerCol1</th>
    <th>BeerCol2</th>
    <th>BeerCol3</th>       
    <th>WineCol1</th>
    <th>WineCol2</th>
    <th>WineCol3</th>
    <th>VodkaCol1</th>
    <th>VodkaCol2</th>
    <th>VodcaCol3</th>
    <th>WhiskeyCol1</th>        
    <th>WhiskeyCol2</th>
    <th>WhiskeyCol3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
           <td>Beer Value 1</td>
           <td>Beer Value 2</td>
           <td>Beer Value 3</td>
           <td>Wine Value 1</td>
           <td>Wine Value 2</td>
           <td>Wine Value 3</td>
           <td>Vodka Value 1</td>
           <td>Vodka Value 2</td>
           <td>Vodka Value 3</td>
           <td>Whiskey Value 1</td>
           <td>Whiskey Value 2</td>
           <td>Whiskey Value 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
           <td>Beer Value 4</td>
           <td>Beer Value 5</td>
           <td>Beer Value 6</td>
           <td>Wine Value 4</td>
           <td>Wine Value 5</td>
           <td>Wine Value 6</td>
           <td>Vodka Value 4</td>
           <td>Vodka Value 5</td>
           <td>Vodka Value 6</td>
           <td>Whiskey Value 4</td>
           <td>Whiskey Value 5</td>
           <td>Whiskey Value 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: @Bhuwan: it should work such that any combination of checked or unchecked selections are made that the appropriate columns for each selection are either visible or hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add attributes, try this:

```css
#beer:checked ~ table .beer,
#whiskey:checked ~ table .whiskey,
#wine:checked ~ table .wine,
#vodka:checked ~ table .vodka {
  visibility: visible;
}

th, td {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
Show: 
<input id="beer" name="beer" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="beer">Beer</label>
<input id="wine" name="wine" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="wine">Wine</label>
<input id="vodka" name="vodka" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="vodka">Vodka</label>
<input id="whiskey" name="whiskey" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="whiskey">Whiskey</label>
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="beer">BeerCol1</th>
  <th class="beer">BeerCol2</th>
  <th class="beer">BeerCol3</th>       
  <th class="wine">WineCol1</th>
  <th class="wine">WineCol2</th>
  <th class="wine">WineCol3</th>
  <th class="vodka">VodkaCol1</th>
  <th class="vodka">VodkaCol2</th>
  <th class="vodka">VodcaCol3</th>
  <th class="whiskey">WhiskeyCol1</th>        
  <th class="whiskey">WhiskeyCol2</th>
  <th class="whiskey">WhiskeyCol3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="beer">Beer Value 1</td>
  <td class="beer">Beer Value 2</td>
  <td class="beer">Beer Value 3</td>
  <td class="wine">Wine Value 1</td>
  <td class="wine">Wine Value 2</td>
  <td class="wine">Wine Value 3</td>
  <td class="vodka">Vodka Value 1</td>
  <td class="vodka">Vodka Value 2</td>
  <td class="vodka">Vodka Value 3</td>
  <td class="whiskey">Whiskey Value 1</td>
  <td class="whiskey">Whiskey Value 2</td>
  <td class="whiskey">Whiskey Value 3</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td class="beer">Beer Value 4</td>
  <td class="beer">Beer Value 5</td>
  <td class="beer">Beer Value 6</td>
  <td class="wine">Wine Value 4</td>
  <td class="wine">Wine Value 5</td>
  <td class="wine">Wine Value 6</td>
  <td class="vodka">Vodka Value 4</td>
  <td class="vodka">Vodka Value 5</td>
  <td class="vodka">Vodka Value 6</td>
  <td class="wine">Whiskey Value 4</td>
  <td class="wine">Whiskey Value 5</td>
  <td class="wine">Whiskey Value 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. This works, but not quite in the way that I would like. It does hide the appropriate columns, but if only Beer and Whiskey were selected then there would be a gap of six columns between the data for Beer and Whiskey. I need the table to "close up" the space such that if Wine and Vodka are removed then the Beer and Whiskey data would be next to each other without the gaps between the column data.

Comment: @ScottParrish use `display:none` and `display:table-cell` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution with jQuery,
I indexed every checkbox from 0 on,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').on('change',function(){
          var id = $(this).data('id')
          
          if ($(this).prop('checked'))
            $('table tr').each(function(i,v){
                $(v).find('td').eq(id).show();
                $(v).find('th').eq(id).show();
            })
          else
             $('table tr').each(function(i,v){
                $(v).find('td').eq(id).hide();
                $(v).find('th').eq(id).hide();
            })

      })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" data-id="0" checked>
    <label for="check1">Beer</label>

    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" data-id="1" checked>
    <label for="check2">Wine</label>

    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" data-id="2" checked>
    <label for="check3">Vodka</label>
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Beer</th>
            <th>Wine</th>
            <th>Vodka</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>34</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```